# Building dictionary of unique IDs for pairs of matching strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this

```
#Test dataframe
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Build df

titles = {'Title': ['title1', 'cat', 'dog']}
references = {'References': [['donkey','chicken'],['title1','dog'],['bird','snake']]}

df = pd.DataFrame({'Title': ['title1', 'cat', 'dog'], 'References': [['donkey','chicken'],['title1','dog'],['bird','snake']]})
#Insert IDs for UNIQUE titles
title_ids = {'IDs':list(np.arange(0,len(df)) + 1)}

df['IDs'] = list(np.arange(0,len(df)) + 1)
df = df[['Title','IDs','References']]
```

[image]

and I want to generate IDs for the references column that looks like the data frame below. If there is a matching between the strings, assign the same ID as in the IDs column and if not, assign a new unique ID.

[image]

My first attempt is using the function

```
#Matching function
def string_match(string1,string2):
    if string1 == string2:
        a = 1
    else:
        a = 0

    return a
```

and to loop over each string/title combination but this gets tricky with multiple for loops and if statements. Is there a better way I can do this that is more pythonic?

Comment: Why does the RefID start at 4 in your picture?

Comment: since donkey is not in the IDs column, i.e. it is a new string, it gets assigned max(IDs) + 1 thus giving it a unique id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
# Explode to one reference per row
references = df["References"].explode()

# Combine existing titles with new title from References
titles = pd.concat([df["Title"], references]).unique()

# Assign each title an index number
mappings = {t: i + 1 for i, t in enumerate(titles)}

# Map the reference to the index number and convert to list
df["RefIDs"] = references.map(mappings).groupby(level=0).apply(list)
```

Comment: How would you suggest altering this approach if say, I wanted to match partial more complex words with the same ID. Say I had 'cat' and 'cats' appearing and I wanted to give them the same ID, using a function for fuzzy matching or approximate string matching?

Comment: You can play around with the `mappings` dictionary to have both `cat` and `cats` map to one ID based on fuzzy matching

Comment: do you have a small WE of how that could be done, simply?

Answer (score 1):

Let us try with `factorize`

```
s = df['References'].explode()
s[:] = pd.concat([df['Title'],s]).factorize()[0][len(df['Title']):]
df['new'] = (s+1).groupby(level=0).agg(list)
Out[237]: 
0    [4, 5]
1    [1, 3]
2    [6, 7]
Name: References, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answers this can also be done with the help of a **function**, **apply** and **lambda**:

```
id_info=dict(df[['Title','IDs']].values)
def check(title,ref):
    new_id_ = max(id_info.values())  #get latest id

    ids=[]
    for i in ref:
        if i in id_info:  #if Reference value is defined before, get its id
            new_id=id_info[i]
        else:
            new_id=new_id_ + 1 #define a new id if not defined before and update dictionary to get latest id in next steps
            new_id_+=1
            id_info.update({i:new_id})          
        ids.append(new_id)
    return ids
    
df['new_id']=df.apply(lambda x: check(x['Title'],x['References']),axis=1)
print(df)
'''
    Title   IDs References              RefIDs
0   title1  1   ['donkey', 'chicken']   [4, 5]
1   cat     2   ['title1', 'dog']       [1, 3]
2   dog     3   ['bird', 'snake']       [6, 7]


'''
```